# System group membership cannot be changed

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I have generated template from existing Azure API management resource, modified it a bit, and tried to deploy using Azure CLI. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 7561a68f-54d1-4370-bf6a-175fd93a4b99. {
      "error": {
        "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "System group membership cannot be changed",
        "details": null
      }
    }
```

But all the APIs are getting created and working fine. Can anyone help me solve the error. This is the command I tried to deploy in my ubuntu machine:

```
az group deployment create -g XXXX --template-file azuredeploy.json --parameters @param.json
```

Service Group Template:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('service_name'), '/administrators')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('service_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Administrators",
                "description": "Administrators is a built-in group. Its membership is managed by the system. Microsoft Azure subscription administrators fall into this group.",
                "type": "system"
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is no such service as Azure API

Comment: API Management Service - Azure Resource Group

Comment: Did you change something related to the group? We can not change the system groups.

Comment: Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups I mean this one.

Comment: the membership of administrators, developers and guests are managed by the system.

Comment: I did not change that..

Comment: @SatZ What did you change?

Comment: I just modified to pass publisher email and name through parameter.

Comment: @TonyJu Updated question with service group template, same is there for developer and guest..

Comment: @SatZ Take a look at this http://www.alessandromoura.com.br/2018/09/13/deploying-api-management-with-arm-templates/ It seems that the template downloaded from azure portal does not expose everything you need to have another instance of it running right away.

Comment: Do you want to create a new apim service(without api) or the same instance of your old apim service?

Comment: same instance of old apim. actually i'm trying that methods in blog which you have commented. but i'm getting file not found exception

Comment: Hi @TonyJu... I just removed administrator, developer parts in user resource :  "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/groups/users". After removing this I could able to deploy successfully.

Comment: @SatZ Thanks for sharing your solution. You can add your solution as the answer. Mine is the general solution without changing the template.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options if you want to copy an API Management instance to a new instance. Using the template is not listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-copy-my-api-management-service-instance-to-a-new-instance).

- Use the backup and restore function in API Management. For more information, see [How to implement disaster recovery by using service backup and restore in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore).
- Create your own backup and restore feature by using the [API Management REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/). Use the REST API to save and restore the entities from the service instance that you want.
- Download the service configuration by using Git, and then upload it to a new instance. For more information, see [How to save and configure your API Management service configuration by using Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git).

**Update:**

I have Confirmed with Microsoft engineer that ARM template deployment for APIM failed is an known issue and is planning to fix it.(5/7/2019)

Comment: Hey Tony, could you provide a link for the issue?